# How to find SQL count diffs relative to a date over time in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

#### What i have:

I have a table that looks like this:

| user | resource | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Account | 2021-01-01T12:00:00 UTC |
| Bob | Homepage | 2021-01-01T12:01:30 UTC |
| Sarah | Terms | 2021-01-02T08:45:10 UTC |
| Sarah | Terms | 2021-01-03T09:04:59 UTC |

Each row corresponds to a user visiting a resource.

#### What i want:

I want a table that looks like this:

| user | resource | count this hour | count last hour | percent gain |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | Account | 500 | 31 | 1612.9% |
| Bob | Homepage | 1 | 0 | 100% |
| Sarah | Account | 0 | 0 | 0% |

Essentially, I want to be able to easily see the change in traffic for the last hour for each user on each resource they've visited. e.g. I can see Bob's traffic to the "Account" resource has spiked.

#### My query so far:

```
SELECT
    user,
    resource,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, HOUR) AS hour,
    COUNT(request) as hour_count
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    user,
    resource,
    hour
```

This gives me each user/resource group's traffic count per hour. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please explain how "count this hour" and "count last hour) are calculated.  It is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,

```
select user, resource,
       countif(timestamp_trunc(hour, timestamp) = timestamp_trunc(hour, current_timestamp)) as count_this_hour,
       countif(timestamp_trunc(hour, timestamp) = timestamp_add(timestamp_trunc(hour, current_timestamp), interval -1 hour)) as count_last_hour,
       (countif(timestamp_trunc(hour, timestamp) = timestamp_trunc(hour, current_timestamp)) /
        nullif(countif(timestamp_trunc(hour, timestamp) = timestamp_add(timestamp_trunc(hour, current_timestamp), interval -1 hour)) 
              )
       ) as ratio
from `table` t
group by user, resource;
```